# Using bokeh server in jupyter notebook behind proxy / jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh, jupyterhub

I want to develop bokeh apps on a jupyter notebook instance that runs behind jupyterhub (AKA an authenticating proxy). I would like to have interactive bokeh apps calling back to the notebook kernel. I don't want to use the notebook widgets etc because I want to be able to export the notebook as a python file and have something I can serve with bokeh server.

The following code in my notebook gives an empty output with no errors:

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
output_notebook()
# Create the Document Application
def modify_doc(doc):
    layout = row(Button(label="Hello,"),Button(label="world!"))
    doc.add_root(layout)

handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)

# Output = BokehJS 0.12.10 successfully loaded.


# New cell
show(app, notebook_url="my-jupyterhub-url.com:80")

# Output = "empty" cell
```

Inspecting the cell a script tag has been added:

```
<script src="http://my-jupyterhub-url.com:46249/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=f8fa3bd0-9caf-473d-87a5-6c7b9680648b&amp;bokeh-absolute-url=http://my-jupyterhub-url.com:46249" id="f8fa3bd0-9caf-473d-87a5-6c7b9680648b" data-bokeh-model-id="" data-bokeh-doc-id=""></script>
```

This will not work because port `46249` isn't open on the jupyterhub proxy. Also the path that routes to **my** jupyter instance is `my-jupyterhub-url.com/user/my-username/` so `my-jupyterhub-url.com/autoload.js` wouldn't route anywhere.

This *feels* like it could be a common requirement but a search hasn't revealed a solution to be yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found a solution that I'm not happy about but works.. just about.

First install `nbserverproxy` on your Jupyter instance. This allows you to proxy through JupyterHub (where you are authenticated) onto arbitrary ports on your Jupyter machine/container. I installed by opening a terminal from the Jupyter web front end and typing:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jupyterhub/nbserverproxy --user
jupyter serverextension enable --py nbserverproxy --user
```

Then restart your server. For my install of JupyterHub this was `control panel` -> `stop my server` wait then `start my server`.

Finally I monkey patched the `Ipython.display.publish_display_data` (since the source code revealed that `bokeh` used this when calling `show`) in the notebook like so.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from IPython.display import publish_display_data
orig = publish_display_data

import re
def proxy_replacer(display_data):
    for key, item in display_data.items():
        if isinstance(item, str):
            item= re.sub(r'(/user/tam203)/?:([0-9]+)', r'\1/proxy/\2', item)
            item = re.sub(r'http:' , 'https:', item)
            display_data[key] = item 
    return display_data


def mock(data, metadata=None, source=None):
    data = proxy_replacer(data) if data else data 
    metadata = proxy_replacer(metadata) if metadata else metadata
    return orig(data, metadata=metadata, source=source)


patcher = patch('IPython.display.publish_display_data', new=mock)
patcher.start()
```

With that all done I was then able to run the following an see a nice dynamically updating plot.

```
import random
from bokeh.io import output_notebook 
output_notebook()
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource


def make_document(doc):
    source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': [], 'color': []})

    def update():
        new = {'x': [random.random()],
               'y': [random.random()],
               'color': [random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])]}
        source.stream(new)

    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 100)

    fig = figure(title='Streaming Circle Plot!', sizing_mode='scale_width',
                 x_range=[0, 1], y_range=[0, 1])
    fig.circle(source=source, x='x', y='y', color='color', size=10)

    doc.title = "Now with live updating!"
    doc.add_root(fig)

app =  Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))
show(app, notebook_url="<my-domain>.co.uk/user/tam203/")
```

So while I'm happy to have found a work around it doesn't really feel like a solution. I think a smallish change in bokeh could solve this (something like a url template string where you can specify the path and the port).

Answer (score 0):

According to the official bokeh [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyterhub) `show(obj, notebook_url=remote_jupyter_proxy_url)` accepts a notebook_url argument value. Apparently this can be a function that accepts a port argument value.

The documentation goes further by providing a reference implementation for the function `remote_jupyter_proxy_url` in the context of jupyterhub/jupyterlab and proxy extension.